# Ajax function with PHP MySQL not calling the php page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a page that lists customers from a SQL database. It lists the credits they have left and I have a button that I can click to remove one credit. The way it is done is when you click on the button it calls a Ajax function that  runs a php page that remopves one credit and echoes the credit after that.

The php page works fine when I input the string in the URL manually but smy Ajax function must be wrong.

here is the listing with the form:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    print "<TR><TD>".$data->pass_name."</TD><TD><span id='credit'>".$data->credit_left."</span></TD><TD><form><input type='submit' value='- 1' onsubmit='removeOneCredit(pass_id=".$data->pass_id."&credit_left=".$data->credit_left.")'></form></TD></TR>\n";

}
```

and here is my function:

```
<script>
function removeOneCredit(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("credit").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("credit").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","removeonecredit.php?"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure why the function is not working. I know for a fact that removeonecredit.php is doing its job.

Comment: Where is the function `removeOneCredit()` being called? And where are you handeling the `$_GET` variables in the PHP code?

Comment: Have a look at the first bit of code: `<form><input type='submit' value='- 1' onsubmit='removeOneCredit(pass_id=".$data->pass_id."&credit_left=".$data->credit_left.")'></form>`  The GET variables are handled in removeonecredit.php and there are no issues with that I tested manually

Comment: which should pass removeonecredit.php?pass_id=1$credit_left=3 for example. When I input that manually it works

Comment: What undesired result do you get when trying to use the AJAX code?

Comment: it just doesn't do anything, it adds a ? at the end of the url but doesn't "execute" the php page I assigned to it. I am brand new to Ajax so this could is mostly pasted from somewehere else

Comment: Try adding `return false;` at the end of the onsubmit attribute to prevent your form element from reloading the page.

Comment: still the same effect, which is none

Comment: Have you placed the script files in the same level folder?

Comment: its in the body of the same php file as the form

Comment: Anyone sees anything wrong with the script itself?

Answer (score 0):

turns out the = in the function arguments is a problem, I posted a question on how to escape it here: [Javascript escape a equal sign PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794271/javascript-escape-a-equal-sign-php)